# How to check if two StateListDrawable(s) are equal?

Tags: android, android-espresso, hamcrest, xml-drawable, statelistdrawable

I'm trying to write a test to check if my ViewGroup has the right background. I'm using Espresso and Hamcrest for the test.

This is the xml file I used for the background of my ViewGroup(RelativeLayout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Attempt 1**

I followed the code from [programcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=friendspell-master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sqisland/friendspell/util/CustomMatchers.java) and I get `GradientDrawable` after `getCurrent` is called on both `expectedDrawable` and `actualDrawable`. Since `GradientDrawable` isn't covered in the example, I tried adding a few code hoping it would work.

```
public static Matcher<View> withBgDrawable(final int expectedResourceId) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

            Drawable actualDrawable = view.getBackground();

            if (expectedResourceId < 0) return actualDrawable == null;

            Drawable expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), expectedResourceId);
            if (expectedDrawable == null) return false;

            if (actualDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
                actualDrawable = actualDrawable.getCurrent();
            }
            if (expectedDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
                expectedDrawable = expectedDrawable.getCurrent();
            }

            if (expectedDrawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
                return actualDrawable instanceof GradientDrawable && gradientToBitmap((GradientDrawable) expectedDrawable)
                        .sameAs(gradientToBitmap((GradientDrawable) actualDrawable));
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported drawable: " + actualDrawable);

        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with drawable ");
        }

    };

}

private static Bitmap gradientToBitmap(GradientDrawable gradientDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(gradientDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), gradientDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    gradientDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gradientDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

this is the error I get.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

So, I logged the value of `gradientDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` to see what's going on and found that it was `-1`.

**Attempt 2**

Then, I tried changing those `StateListDrawable`(s) directly into `Bitmap`(s). I get the same error as attempt 1.

```
public static Matcher<View> withBgDrawable(final int expectedResourceId) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

            Drawable actualDrawable = view.getBackground();

            if (expectedResourceId < 0) return actualDrawable == null;

            Drawable expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), expectedResourceId);
            if (expectedDrawable == null) return false;

            if (expectedDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
                return actualDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable && stateListToBitmap((StateListDrawable) expectedDrawable)
                        .sameAs(stateListToBitmap((StateListDrawable) actualDrawable));
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported drawable: " + actualDrawable);

        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with drawable ");
        }

    };

}

private static Bitmap stateListToBitmap(StateListDrawable stateListDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(stateListDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), stateListDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    stateListDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    stateListDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

**Attempt 3**

If I simply use `equals` or `==` on either `StateListDrawable` or `GradientDrawable`, drawables from the same xml file do not match.

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError:
>   'with drawable ' doesn't match the selected view.

Comment: Try using the view's width and height instead in the first attempt